# Paste data moving UP

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

Can someone provide a code that says something like:  STARTING AT THE BOTTOM, if value in "C" is blank look to "B" (if not blank copy value in C and D); if "B" is blank look to "A" (if not blank copy value in B and D); if "A" is blank then move to next (if not blank copy value in A and D).

I need the script to start at the bottom of the page and move UP.  For example, start at row 9 and end when the logic has run through row 1.

The end result using the below data should look like:

```
END RESULT
color      12  
primary    35  
blue       1  
shape      685  
rounded    1  
oval       25  
size       21  
big        56  
giant      10  


DATA:  
     A       B        C      D
1   size    big     giant   10  
2   size    big             56  
3   size                    21  
4   shape   rounded oval    25  
5   shape   rounded          1  
6   shape                   685  
7   color   primary blue    1  
8   color   primary         35  
9   color                   12
```

Comment: Your question would be clearer if you edit your sample data and required result to include at least one case where A is blank.

Comment: How about providing feedback and or marking your last questions as solved before starting new ones.

Answer (score 1):

I do not understand why it is essential to move up since there is no relationship between the rows.

Copy the following formula into E1 and copy down and you get the values you seek.

```
=IF(C1="",IF(B1="",A1,B1),C1)
```

This is not in reverse sequence which is how you list the required result.  Do you want it sorted or are you just showing the calculation sequence?

**Extra section in respond to additional information**

Go to the bottom of column F, currently F9 and type:

```
=ROW(F$9)-ROW(F9)
```

Copy this formula up the column to give you the numbers 0 up to 8.  You can now sort by column F into ascending or descending sequence depending on which view you wish.

I will leave Siddharth Rout to give you the VBA equivalent of this.  By the way, Siddharth has created two additional columns so the result is in the column sequence you show.  I thought this was a nice addition.  You can do the same with formulae if you prefer the formula approach.

Comment: I need it in reverse sequencing because Color needs to be above Primary which is above Blue.

Answer (score 1):

Tony has already give you the easiest way to achieve what you want but if you still want a code which gives you the EXACT output as yours then try this. The output will be in Col F:G

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim LastRow As Long, Rw As Long, i As Long

    LastRow = Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Rw = 1

    For i = LastRow To 1 Step -1
        If Len(Trim(Range("C" & i).Value)) = 0 Then
            If Len(Trim(Range("B" & i).Value)) = 0 Then
                If Len(Trim(Range("A" & i).Value)) <> 0 Then
                    Range("F" & Rw).Value = Range("A" & i).Value
                    Range("G" & Rw).Value = Range("D" & i).Value
                End If
            Else
                Range("F" & Rw).Value = Range("B" & i).Value
                Range("G" & Rw).Value = Range("D" & i).Value
            End If
        Else
            Range("F" & Rw).Value = Range("C" & i).Value
            Range("G" & Rw).Value = Range("D" & i).Value
        End If

        Rw = Rw + 1
    Next i
End Sub
```